# Has facebook changed things

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has facebook done a recent change or anything? I have looked and looked but cant find anything on this.

I used to be able to get back a list of a users facebook fan pages but now i'm getting back an empty data string data[]. Do I need a different type of access token or something?

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: What request are you attempting?

Comment: Generally speaking, Facebook is *always* changing things. (They have a lot of programmers and they program...) Keep track in their developer forums, here, and blogs. Also, they pay attention to good incoming bug reports filed on their bugzilla system--a well documented error with a simple test case has gotten me good results from FB in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to get the pages the user is an admin of..  Facebook recently (October 1st) changed the /me/accounts to only return information if the user has granted the "manage_pages" permission.

See the roadmap's completed items.
http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/561/